# Meaning of the expression "Anda la juez"

Tags: traducción

Years ago when I was in college, I had a teacher who used the phrase "Anda la juez."  Sometimes she said "Ande la juez", so I'm assuming the verb is being used as a command, since it's in the familiar (tú) form in the first sentence and in the formal (usted) form in the second.

I didn't want to seem like an idiot at the time and ask what it meant, so many years later I will use the anonymity of the Internet to look like an idiot here.  What does "anda la juez" mean?

Comment: I have never heard this expression in Spain. Where was this teacher from? It may be something specific from a country.

Comment: Literally it can be translated to "Let the judge go". In my opinion it may be paraphrased as "Qué se vaya la juez". What is the hidden meaning of that I cannot say and would not try to.

Comment: The teacher was from Mexico.

Comment: I have just asked my friend Homero from México and he claims that he has never heard such a phrase in his life. He is from Mexico City. But he also says that there are so many regions there that it might be plausible that it is used "en alguna provincia".

Comment: With no additional context, I would guess this is just an exclamation expressing surprise. We have many *Anda la <whatever>* idioms, where *<whatever>* can be any of a different number of words, all of them expressing surprise. Even just *¡Anda!* expresses surprise.

Comment: Another option: it may be just a variation on *¡Ándale!*, a very common exclamation in Mexico.

Comment: If I remember correctly, this particular teacher was from Guadalajara.  To put this in context, she usually said it to me when I was saying goodbye to her at the end of class.

Comment: Me inclino a pensar que, si lo decía al despedirse, podría haber estado diciendo "Ándale pues". En [este hilo de Wordreference.com](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/andale-%C3%A1ndale-pues.39973/) explican que es una expresión que se usa en situaciones como esa.

Comment: I agree with @JMVanPelt. I would think you misheard the sentence and she was saying "ándele pues!' or "ándale pues!" which means "go ahead", "go on" or "move on". This is a very common expression in Mexico.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The verb [Andar](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?id=dGzDMZMZ7DXX2z7yfabs) has several meanings. Among them

> Ir de un lugar a otro (dando pasos).

Which basically is "to walk" or to "go from one place to another". It can also mean

> estar (hallarse en un determinado estado)

With the connotation of "being in a particular state, condition or mood".

It can mean so many things that, given the short sentence, the lack of context and that we don't know where your teacher learn her Spanish is impossible to know for sure. The sentence `Anda la juez` is not a colloquialism or expression.

One guess is that it could be using the meaning of the entry #8 of the link

> Obrar, proceder.

with the meaning "the Judge made a decision". `Ande la juez` would then be "May the judge make a decision" and `Anda la juez` would mean "The judge is making a decision/ the judge makes a decision". But this is just a wild guess of mine.

Again, there could be other meanings shall the sentence not be that short.

> Anda la juez **preocupada**  <sub>The judge is worried</sub>
>
> Anda la juez **encorvada/lentamente**  <sub>The judge walks hunched/slowly</sub>

Comment: I disagree with this answer.  Based on the OP's comments, the more likely explanation is a form of "andale pues"

Comment: @Paul, completamente de acuerdo. Mi respuesta responde a la pregunta original. Tu respuesta, que ya tiene mi +1, es una respuesta "out of the box". Responde a la pregunta (resuelve la duda) sin responder a la pregunta original (basándose en la idea de que el OP no entendió bien la expresión).

Answer (score 6):

You state three important facts in your comments:

1. The teacher was from Mexico.
2. She said it when saying goodbye.
3. It was years ago

Based upon this evidence, I would speculate one of two possibilities:

1. She actually said "andale pues", but your memory may not recall the words correctly (I mean no afront to your mental capacities: we're all human and we all forget sometimes).
2. Your teacher was using a play on words on the phrase "Andale pues".  It is common in Mexico to say "Andale pues" just before saying goodbye.  Also, if you are familiar with Mexican culture, we like to play with words.  For reference, lookup [Albur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albur) and [Calo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cal%C3%B3_%28Chicano%29).

Either way, the intent of your teacher was most likely "andale pues".